# vim let mapleader = "\<Space>" annoying cursor movement

Tags: vim

I'm trying to map space bar to leader key by using the code above but there's a problem - it is writing the file but whenever I press space, the pointer moves forward a character, which annoys me. What am I missing? (gvim@arch linux) Here's my .vimrc

```
let mapleader = "\<Space>"

nnoremap <Leader> :w<CR>
```

Changing the code to

```
let mapleader = " "
```

makes no difference. I've tried to append the line `noremap <Space> <Nop>` to it but to no avail. What am I missing?

Comment: I bel you just sourced your vimrc. You need to restart vim as leader mapping are decided at the time the mapping is created. Changing leader afterwords will not change the mappings.

Comment: @FDinoff I've even restarted my pc :) but to no avail!!

Comment: @use_vim I am mapping to the default leader using map <space> \ -- this way it works with `showcmd`. Source: http://superuser.com/a/693644/98798

Answer (score 4):

Space can be a bit tricky. Why not just map space to `<leader>`

```
nmap <space> <leader>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
let mapleader=" "
nnoremap <Space> <Nop>
```

Notice the `nnoremap` not `noremap`

`noremap` will try to remap it for all modes but leader is only used in normal mode so `nnoremap` will give the intended behavior (also space is pretty useful in insert mode so its nice to have it not be remapped to `<Nop>` there).

Comment: Put it at the top of your vimrc. Its working for me.

Comment: not working, but interestingly, any code works on my mac(macvim)

Comment: Could you post your vimrc file?

Comment: And the problem is not that pressing the space key doesn't trigger `leader` keybindings but just that pressing space moves the cursor forward one character?

Comment: the problem is that it writes the file AND moves ahead - this moving ahead part is objectionable to me.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have an "imap" or "inoremap" that starts with the leader key. You can use `verb imap <leader>` in command mode to check that.

Remove the mapping and you should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

just make sure you didn't leave any extra space at the end of `<leader>`, it will be read by the mapping statement.